# Animating stateful list item on the basis of api changes Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Is there any way I can animate a single list item (say glowing border of a container) on the basis of changes on api? I have a listview which has price of items and when price changes in real time, I want to animate that particular item container. I have been searching for a solution for months now and I haven't found any yet.

```
StreamBuilder<MyProducts>(
                stream: myProductsBloc.subject.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.data.error != null &&
                        snapshot.data.error.length > 0) {
                      return ShowError(
                        error: snapshot.data.error,
                        onTap: () => myProductsBloc.getMyProducts(),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.data.data.length == 0) {
                      return EmptyWidget();
                    }
                    return ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (context, i) =>
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                            ProductData productData = snapshot.data.data[i];
                            return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () =>
                                    _buildBottomSheet(argument: productData),
                                child: ProductCard(product: productData));
                          },
                       
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('${snapshot.data.error}'),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                        child: LoadingWidget(text: "Fetching products.."));
                  }
                }),
```

Here I want to animate border of product card if price on the api changes.

Comment: use `AnimatedContainer`

Comment: I tried but it animates all of the items on the listview and not one specific one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't do exactly that but I added one element "animate" as a bool in item model. It is false by default but when data changes I injected true on the model and it works now. Maybe bad practice but it works for now.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

in pseudo code,
Border(borderWidth: (myListItemId == 'special' ? controller_value*2 : 1)

...should do. With colors it is a bit more tricky, but you could use an index of a list with colors

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't do exactly like this, instead I added a bool in model and made it true in case I needed to animate that item and false by default. It works for now.

Comment: accepting the answer then is always a nice gesture ;-)

Comment: That's true but I didn't technically implement your answer so I was thinking of writing my own answer on how I did it. Hope you don't mind :)